# bitbucket pipeline python appengine suddently started failing

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, bitbucket-pipelines

All of a sudden bitbucket pipeline started failing getting below error

> ```
> DEBUG: Operation [apps/$PROJECT/operations/sdfdf-bec2-4da5-b215-475a43ebdd77] not
> ```
>
> complete. Waiting to retry.
> Updating service [default]...
> .....DEBUG: Operation [apps/$PROJECT/operations/sdfdsf-bec2-4da5-b215-475a43ebdd77] not
> complete. Waiting to retry.
> ............................DEBUG: Operation [apps/$PROJECT/operations/sdfsdf-bec2-4da5-b215-475a43ebdd77] not
> complete. Waiting to retry.
> ...............................DEBUG: Operation [apps/$PROJECT/operations/sdf-bec2-4da5-b215-475a43ebdd77] not
> complete. Waiting to retry.
> ...........................DEBUG: Operation [apps/$PROJECT/operations/sdfsf-bec2-4da5-b215-475a43ebdd77] not
> complete. Waiting to retry.
> ..............................DEBUG: Operation [apps/$PROJECT/operations/sdfdsf-bec2-4da5-b215-475a43ebdd77] not
> complete. Waiting to retry.
> sdf

got the link https://groups.google.com/g/google-appengine/c/r7mADCM4LNg facing same error, but its not in pipeline, its suggesting changing the gcloud sdk version, but In pipeline how can I change the pipeline I tried changing

from `atlassian/google-app-engine-deploy:0.4.1`
to `atlassian/google-app-engine-deploy:1.2.0`

but nothing helped

I have already given all required permission

any help
Thanks